# display values of couchdb document

Tags: ruby, couchdb

I have a document stored in couchdb which is like this -

```
{
 "_id": "0f8baf09c680abdc434607dc77000bad",
 "_rev": "2-c989a4c672d25b678aadfa4c37212404",
 "XI": "gl11subjects",
"XII": "gl12subjects"
}
```

when I retrieve the document using the code

```
@value = CouchRest.get("url/db/docid")

@value.each do |key, value| 

puts "Key: "+key+"value: "+value+
```

The above statement prints all the values in the json file, including _id and _rev.
How should I iterate through the @value to only get the key/value for XI and XII.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
@value.each do |key, value|
puts "Key: #{key} Value: #{value}" if key.include?("XI")
end
```

Inversely, you could do the following:

```
@value.each do |key, value|
puts "Key: #{key} Value: #{value}" unless key.include?("_")
end
```